# How to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of general vector spaces

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

up to now I only encountered eigenvalues/vectors for matrices. How would I find it for general vector spaces? Do I still compute a matrix usually?

Specifically, for this question
Let the vector space be the space of real cubic polynomials, compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the transformation $T(p) = p(1-t)+p(1+t)$ where $p$ is a function that takes in values $t$ and is a cubic polynomial.  I see that $2$ is probably an eigenvalue, but the solution says $0$ is also an eigenvalue... which I don't see how. I also am unsure how to compute the eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. What is the eigenvalue equation for T(p) -- use your knowledge of the matrix version.
2. If p is a cubic polynomial what is its most general form? What are the "free parameters" that will play the role of your vector entries? In this case, T plays the role of your matrix.
3. What happens when you put the result of point 2 into the transformation T?
4. Combine this with the requirements of point 1. What does this imply for your free parameters (that are no longer so free....)?

Continue now as you would for matrices

Comment: Here was my attempt.  
$T(p) = p(1-t) + p(1+t) = 2p$. Then let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$, then we have $2p = \lambda p \implies p(2-\lambda) = 0$. Hence, since $p$ cannot equal zero (since we cannot have a zero eigenvector by definition), then $p=2$.  
How would I find the eigenbasis for this?  
Would this answer be easier if I let $p(t) = a_0  + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3$?

Comment: I believe that where you see p(1-t) you are to evaluate the cubic polynomial -- point 2 -- at 1-t. E.g if p is the  polynomial p(t) = 2t then p(1-t) = 2(1-t) = 2 - 2t. Point 1 will tell you that p(t) = 2t is thus not an Eigenfunction. Does that help clarify what p(1-t) means?

Comment: Thanks. not sure how to derive some matrix with the free parameters. Equating the relationship btwn. eigenvalues and the transformation, I'm only getting $\lambda = 0$ now, since we must have equivalence, and the expansion will have the coefficient of $t^3$ to be zero, which equals $\lambda$.

Comment: The polynomial I gave is not the most general cubic polynomial. What is your attempt at point 2 in my post? Hint: the most general polynomial with maximal power $t^3$ will have four arbitrary parameters / unknown constants. What will its form be?

Comment: For example, I could just as well have had $p(t)  = 1 + 2t^3$...